# Google Sheets Formula - Return Lowest Populated Row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheets workbook with many sheets(tabs), each with various lines of data in ascending order (the lowest line being the most up-to-date data).  I would like to create a "summary" sheet that returns the lowest populated row from each sheet.  Any ideas?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
=INDEX({
 INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(MAX(Sheet1!A1:A<>"")*(ROW(Sheet1!A1:A))), 1));
 INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&ADDRESS(MAX(Sheet2!A1:A<>"")*(ROW(Sheet2!A1:A))), 1));
 INDIRECT("Sheet3!"&ADDRESS(MAX(Sheet3!A1:A<>"")*(ROW(Sheet3!A1:A))), 1))})
```

this will give you the latest value in A column from each of the sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)